# How do I calculate the covariance matrix without any built-in functions or loops in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is it possible to find the covariance of a matrix without using any built-in functions or loops in MATLAB?  I'm completely clueless about the idea of solving this problem.

I was thinking of something like:

```
cov(x,y) = 1/(n-1) .* (x*y)
```

However, I don't think this will work. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Why don't you want any built-in functions? 2. Why don't you want any loops? 3. "... I don't _think_ this will work". <- Haven't you tried it?

Comment: The covariance requires that you sum up element over columns in a matrixs.  If you can't use built-in functions to sum up elements, then I don't know how you can do this without `for` loops.

Comment: I figured out how to do it without any built-in functions (i.e. `sum` and `bsxfun`... except for `size`, because we need to know how many rows of the matrix there are in your data).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a great example of how to numerically compute the covariance matrix.  http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section5/pmc541.htm.  However, let's put this in this post for the sake of completeness.  <s>I'm a bit confused with what you mean by "built-in" functions because the covariance requires that you sum over columns of a matrix.  If you can't use any built-in functions to sum up these elements, then I don't see how you can do this without using `for` loops.</s>   **Edit:** I figured out how to do it without using built-in functions or loops, but you need to use [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) to determine how many rows in the matrix you have... unless you specify this as a constant in your function.

Numerically, you compute the covariance matrix like so:

[image]

Essentially, the i<sup>th</sup> row and the j<sup>th</sup> column of your covariance matrix is such that you take the sum of products of the column `i` minus the mean of column `i` with column `j` minus the mean of column `j`.  Now, add these up, then divide by `n - 1`.  This is known as the [**unbiased estimator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation).  You'll also notice that this matrix is symmetric because even if you flip the order around (i.e. looking at column `j` then column `i` after), the answer should still be the same.  I'm assuming you can't use [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) from MATLAB either so let's do this from first principles.

First, compute a row vector that computes the mean of every column.  What you can do to compute the sum over all of the columns without using [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html), as it is also a built-in function, is multiply this row vector of 1s with your matrix `A`,  The output will be a row vector that contains the sum over all of the columns.  As such, do this:

```
one_vector(1:size(A,1)) = 1;
mu = (one_vector * A) / size(A,1);
```

The trick with the first line of code is that we are dynamically creating an array that is of the same length as the number of rows in your matrix `A`.  We fill this completely full of 1s.  Note that you could have used [`ones`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html), but you said you can't use any built-in functions.  `mu` will contain our vector over all columns.

Now, let's pre-process the data by subtracting every column with the mean, since that's what the definition says we do.  To do this without any built-in functions, what you can do is to subtract all of the columns with their own respective means, duplicate `mu` for as many times as we have 1s in the `one_vector`.  Therefore:

```
A_mean_subtract = A - mu(one_vector, :);
```

Here's where it gets a bit tricky (and cool).  If we transpose the matrix `A`, you'll see that the rows become the columns and the columns become the rows.  If we took this transpose and multiplied by the original matrix, we would actually get the sum of products between column `i` and column `j` of our matrix `A`.  That's the first part of our covariance calculation.  We then divide by `n - 1`.  Therefore, our covariance is simply:

```
covA = (A_mean_subtract.' * A_mean_subtract) / (size(A,1) - 1);
```

Here's a quick example, as well as what is seen on that website I showed you above.  Supposing `A` was this:

```
A = [4 2 0.5; 4.2 2.1 0.59; 3.9 2.0 0.58; 4.3 2.1 0.62; 4.1 2.2 0.63]

A =

    4.0000    2.0000    0.5000
    4.2000    2.1000    0.5900
    3.9000    2.0000    0.5800
    4.3000    2.1000    0.6200
    4.1000    2.2000    0.6300
```

Running through the above code, this is what we get:

```
covA =

    0.0250    0.0075    0.0042
    0.0075    0.0070    0.0034
    0.0042    0.0034    0.0026
```

You'll see that this also matches with the `cov` function in MATLAB too:

```
>> cov(A)

ans =

0.0250    0.0075    0.0042
0.0075    0.0070    0.0034
0.0042    0.0034    0.0026
```

## Bit of a hint

If you type in `edit cov` in your MATLAB command prompt, you can actually see how they compute the covariance matrix without any `for` loops.... and this is essentially the same answer I gave you :)

## If you want to do this more efficiently

Assuming you can use `sum` and `bsxfun`, we can do this in fewer (and more efficiently..) lines of code.  First, compute your mean vector like we did above using `sum`:

```
mu = sum(A) / size(A,1);
```

Now, to subtract your matrix `A` with each column's corresponding mean, you can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to help you facilitate this subtraction:

```
A_mean_subtract = bsxfun(@minus, A, mu);
```

Now, compute your covariance matrix like you did before:

```
covA = (A_mean_subtract.' * A_mean_subtract) / (size(A,1) - 1);
```

You should get exactly the same result as we saw before.

## Minor note on stability

We are using the straight up definition of calculating the covariance between two columns using the definition.  However, it has been shown that using the straight up definition can lend to numerical instability if you provide certain types of data.  Consult [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Covariance) that goes through various algorithms on computing the covariance between two `n` length vectors that are more stable.

Comment: Isn’t `*` as much a built-in function as `sum`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Please note this post was made in 2014, when `sum` did not have broadcasting capabilities.  I have not updated this post yet to reflect current times.  I was updating it to update the covariance matrix equation that was not rendering.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I’m just questioning the use of the `*` operator, which I see as a built-in function, but avoid `sum`. OP’s premise is flawed, not using built-in functions is dumb, and makes MATLAB useless. The whole point of MATLAB is its library. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo ah yes sorry. This poster has a bit of history. He was taking a MATLAB course with a tutor who insisted he learn the language without any "built-ins". It got to a point where the questions became unreasonable without their use so we stopped answering the questions. This of course is the wrong way to learn the language. We should take use of its library as you've so mentioned!